# variable lengths differ error in a aggragate

Tags: r, aggregate

I have some data that I would like to summarize:

```
    studentid friend Gfriend
214  30401006      0       0
236  30401006      0       0
208  30401006      1       0
229  30401006      0       0
207  30401006      0       0
278  30401007      1       0
250  30401007      1       0
266  30401007      1       0
254  30401007      1       1
277  30401007      1       1
243  30401007      1       1
```

result should look something like this:

```
studentid friend Gfriend
30401006   1      0
30401007   6      3
```

When I try: `agg=aggregate(c(friend)~studentid,data=df,FUN=sum)` I get the required result (but only for the friend variable). 
But when I try: `agg=aggregate(c(friend,Gfriend)~studentid,data=df,FUN=sum)` I get:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = c(friend, Gfriend) ~ studentid,
>   :    variable lengths differ (found for 'studentid')

I checked the lengths of the variables ( length(var) ) and they are all the same, plus there are no NA's so I have no idea where this error is coming from.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You were close, try `cbind` instead of `c` as in `aggregate(cbind(friend, Gfriend) ~ studentid, df, sum)`

Comment: Or, if you don't have other columns in your data, you can just do: `aggregate(. ~ studentid, df, sum)`

Comment: How do i use David's code without throwing out NA's. There are no NA's in the example I gave but there are NA's in the full data I'm summarizing and the previous code omits them. I tried na.pass but than I got NA as a result in the coulmns that have NA's.

Comment: Replace NAs using `case_when` & `is.na`.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try "by"

```
 studentid < c(30401006,30401006,30401006,30401006,30401006,30401007,
 + 30401007,30401007,30401007,30401007,30401007)
 friend <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
 Gfriend <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
 df <- data.frame(studentid,friend,Gfriend)
 df

 > result <- by(df[c(2:3)], df$studentid, FUN=colSums)

 > result
 df$studentid: 30401006
 friend Gfriend 
 1       0 
 df$studentid: 30401007
 friend Gfriend 
 6       3
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: added `na.rm = T` to address the comment about excluding NAs

Check out the "plyr" package.

```
library(plyr)

#split by "studentid" and sum all numeric colums 

ddply(df, .(studentid), numcolwise(sum, na.rm=T))

studentid friend Gfriend
1  30401006      1       0
2  30401007      6       3
```